# What does it mean "patient K"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean "patient K"? I [googled it](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=cWEIW9KTOIPRswGwyrKgCQ&q=%22patient%20k%22&oq=%22patient%20k%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23769.23901.0.24402.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ybSSY20lzvM) to find an answer, but I found a lot of results without explanation to this term. What is "**patient K**"?

> Clinical Example: **Patient K**., 54 years old, during 15 years has
>   been suffering from type II DM (Diabetes Mellitus) with periodic
>   phenomena of decompensation... ([Obesity and Diabetes Mellitus - Book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=32fa94IY2zcC&pg=PA252&lpg=PA252&dq=%22patient%20k%22%2039%20years%20old&source=bl&ots=XLh6PjL5_s&sig=wci22MYUwipES8e-KnIDeXbFnLI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZsuS966HbAhWKCywKHcgUAggQ6AEIRDAI#v=onepage&q=%22patient%20k%22%20&f=false))

Another one: 
"Fig. 1. Patient K. with arteriovenous macrofistulous dysplasia of facial soft tissues before surgery." ([researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Patient-K-with-arteriovenous-macrofistulous-dysplasia-of-facial-soft-tissues-before_fig1_6437452))

Now, I don't think it is just an ordinal letter as (A,B,C,....K etc.) since it appears in places in which there are 3-4 questions only without referring to other letters at all.

Comment: You've provided no context. I don't think it means anything. I suppose one might have done a medical study, and then referred to each of the patients as Patient A, Patient B, etc.

Comment: The next patient in line after Patient J and before Patient L?

Comment: In 1958 aged 6 I had a schoolbook in which I met Lonely G - he was always getting left behind when people went fishin', ridin' and so on. Maybe he could learn from Patient K.

Comment: Where did you see/hear it? Also you should add examples (not links) for what you found on your Google search.

Comment: Could be a patient named "Kevin" or "Kathy" or something whose name is being kept anonymous?

Comment: Your additional examples, especially with the period after K, make me even more convinced that they are simply talking about a patient whose real first or last name probably starts with K, but not giving the patient's full name. I'm betting you could find examples with almost any letter of the alphabet. I'm not sure, though, so I can't make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless otherwise indicated that there is some *defined progression* of patients in the study from Patient A through Patient K, then I would assume it's a convention of the medical journal where to use the first letter of the patient's name (probably last name) to preserve anonymity.

So "K" is short for some longer name, like "Kardashian, K.", "Kennedy. J.F.", "Khan, G.", "Kidman, N.", and so on.